# A faster process for migrating questions from other sites?

Tags: discussion, policies, stackexchange, related-stack-exchange-sites, migration

Occasionally a question gets migrated from a different site to this one (e.g. Chem.SE, Physics.SE, etc.). This often happens after a diamond moderator from a different site consults us in the MMSE chat rooms to see whether or not we'd be happy to accept these migrated questions.

One thing I've noticed is that 100% of the time when a diamond moderator from a different site proposes to migrate a question here, they have been ***correct*** that we'd be happy to accept the question here.

**Therefore, I wonder if anyone here would have a problem with us telling diamond mods from other sites that they're welcome to migrate without asking us?**

Considering that migrations happen so rarely anyway, and when they do, they've always been from one of a very small number of other science-related sites, and the diamond moderators proposing the migrations have always had good judgement (correctly deciding to suggest a migration to MMSE), shall we just tell them that it's okay to do this without asking us?

The delay between asking us and us answering, followed by the delay between us answering and them seeing our answer, can be a few hours or maybe even a day. During this time the OP's question is sometimes closed on the first site, and their question is perhaps not getting the amount of attention that it could be getting, from the people who are most likely to be able to answer their question. Furthermore, the formula for the HNQ score decreases ***exponentially*** with respect to the number of hours since the question was asked, meaning that this waiting period could be the difference between the user's question getting maybe ~30 views versus maybe 5000 views (quite a big difference!).

Comment: I'm fine with this, especially since it can sometimes take awhile before I see a chat message. We have generally been fairly receptive to what Chem, Phys, etc has migrated here. Since its a small percentage of our questions and an even smaller amount that are a poor fit, I'm fine with having this as the policy.